# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{\alpha -1}y^{\beta -1}}{\left( 1+xy \right)\ln xy}dxdy}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

On AoPS (Art of Problem Solving), the following integral was posted by fellow user pprime, but no one has been able to come close to solving it. Many attempts have been made, but none have succeeded. I have come here as a last resort so that some kind user would help me evaluate this integral.

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1288609_extreme_integration_marathon

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{\alpha -1}y^{\beta -1}}{\left( 1+xy \right)\ln xy}dxdy}}$$

Hint: $\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\exp \left( -u\ln \left( xy \right) \right)du}=\frac{1}{\ln x+\ln y}$

Comment: What is AoPS ?...

Comment: @JeanMarie Art of Problem Solving

Comment: Thanks for the information. I should maybe have guessed...

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\alpha-\beta} \log{\left( \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{\beta +1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{\alpha +1}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{\beta}{2})} \right)} \text{ for } \alpha < \beta$$

Can someone confirm my answer?

Comment: @JackLam Looks like your answer ended up being correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I\left( \alpha ,\beta \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{\alpha -1}y^{\beta -1}}{\left( 1+xy \right)\ln xy}dxdy}}=-\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\frac{x^{\alpha -1}y^{\beta -1}}{1+xy}\left( xy \right)^{j}djdxdy}}}=-\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{x^{\alpha -1}y^{\beta -1}}{1+xy}\left( xy \right)^{j}dxdydj}}}$

$=-\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -xy \right)^{k}\cdot }x^{\alpha +j-1}y^{\beta +j-1}dxdydj}}}=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{k}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\int\limits_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha +k+j-1}y^{\beta +k+j-1}dxdydj}}}}$

$=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{k}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \int\limits_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha +k+j-1}dx} \right)\left( \int\limits_{0}^{1}{y^{\beta +k+j-1}dy} \right)dj}}=-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{k}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{\left( \alpha +k+j \right)\left( \beta +k+j \right)} \right)dj}}$

$=-\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{k}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{\alpha +k+j-\left( \beta +k+j \right)}{\left( \alpha +k+j \right)\left( \beta +k+j \right)} \right)dj}}$

$=-\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{k}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1}{\beta +k+j}-\frac{1}{\alpha +k+j} \right)dj}}=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( -1 \right)^{k}\ln \left( \frac{\beta +k}{\alpha +k} \right)}$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\left( \left( -1 \right)^{0}\ln \left( \frac{\beta +0}{\alpha +0} \right)+\left( -1 \right)^{1}\ln \left( \frac{\beta +1}{\alpha +1} \right)+\left( -1 \right)^{2}\ln \left( \frac{\beta +2}{\alpha +2} \right)+\left( -1 \right)^{3}\ln \left( \frac{\beta +3}{\alpha +3} \right)+... \right)$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\left( \ln \left( \frac{\beta +0}{\alpha +0} \right)-\ln \left( \frac{\beta +1}{\alpha +1} \right)+\ln \left( \frac{\beta +2}{\alpha +2} \right)-\ln \left( \frac{\beta +3}{\alpha +3} \right)+... \right)$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\left( \ln \left( \frac{\beta +0}{\alpha +0} \right)+\ln \left( \frac{\alpha +1}{\beta +1} \right)+\ln \left( \frac{\beta +2}{\alpha +2} \right)+\ln \left( \frac{\alpha +3}{\beta +3} \right)+... \right)$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \left( \left( \frac{\beta +0}{\alpha +0} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{\alpha +1}{\beta +1} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{\beta +2}{\alpha +2} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{\alpha +3}{\beta +3} \right)\cdot ... \right)=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \prod\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{\beta +2k}{\alpha +2k} \right)\left( \frac{\alpha +1+2k}{\beta +1+2k} \right)}$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \frac{\beta }{\alpha }\cdot \frac{\alpha +1}{\beta +1}\cdot \prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{1+\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k}}{1+\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k}}\cdot \frac{1+\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k}}{1+\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k}} \right)}$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \frac{\beta }{\alpha }\cdot \frac{\alpha +1}{\beta +1}\cdot \prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{e^{\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}}{e^{\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}} \right)}$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \frac{\beta }{\alpha }\cdot \frac{\alpha +1}{\beta +1}\cdot \prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{e^{\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}}{e^{\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}\cdot e^{\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k} \right)^{-1}} \right)}$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \left( \frac{\frac{e^{-\gamma \frac{\alpha }{2}}}{\frac{\alpha }{2}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( e^{\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\alpha }{2}}{k} \right)^{-1} \right)}\cdot \frac{e^{-\gamma \frac{\beta +1}{2}}}{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( e^{\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\beta +1}{2}}{k} \right)^{-1} \right)}}{\frac{e^{-\gamma \frac{\beta }{2}}}{\frac{\beta }{2}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( e^{\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\beta }{2}}{k} \right)^{-1} \right)}\cdot \frac{e^{-\gamma \frac{\alpha +1}{2}}}{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}\prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty }{\left( e^{\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k}}\left( 1+\frac{\frac{\alpha +1}{2}}{k} \right)^{-1} \right)}} \right)$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha -\beta }\ln \left( \frac{\Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha }{2} \right)\cdot \Gamma \left( \frac{\beta +1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma \left( \frac{\beta }{2} \right)\cdot \Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha +1}{2} \right)} \right)$

Comment: In your first step you make a replace the $ln(xy)$ with an integral over $j$ of $(xy)^j$. According to your hint shouldn't this be $(xy)^{-j}$?

Comment: Nope, I'm correct.

Comment: Can you explain why? I was going to upvote your answer until I saw that.

Comment: If you look carefully at the exponentiation, you'll see a double negative on the exponent as per my hint. And that results in the exponent being a positive.

Comment: Ok I think I see it. The negative in front of the integral on the second step converts $\ln(xy)=-\ln(1/xy)$ then you apply the hint to that and get $(xy)^j$ for positive $j$.

Comment: @Spencer Correct! I'm glad you caught that! :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to note that with [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) we can arrive at the infinite product rather quickly. We have that $$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{\alpha-1}y^{\beta-1}}{\left(1+xy\right)\log\left(xy\right)}dxdy\stackrel{xy=u}{=}\int_{0}^{1}y^{\beta-\alpha-1}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{u^{\alpha-1}}{\left(1+u\right)\log\left(u\right)}dudy
 $$ $$\stackrel{IBP}{=}\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{\alpha-1}-y^{\beta-1}}{\left(1+y\right)\log\left(y\right)}dy=\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{\alpha-1+k}-y^{\beta-1+k}}{\log\left(y\right)}dy$$ $$\stackrel{y=e^{-v}}{=}\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-v(\alpha+k)}-e^{-v(\beta+k)}}{v}dv
 $$ and now we can use the Frullani's theorem and get $$I(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\log\left(\frac{\beta+k}{\alpha+k}\right)=\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\log\left(\prod_{k\geq0}\left(\frac{\beta+2k+1}{\alpha+2k+1}\right)\left(\frac{\beta+2k}{\alpha+2k}\right)^{-1}\right)
 $$ now note that $$\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(a+2k\right)=2^{N}\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(\frac{a}{2}+k\right)=2^{N}a\left(\frac{a}{2}+1\right)_{N}
 $$ and $$\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(a+2k+1\right)=2^{N}\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(k+\frac{a+1}{2}\right)=\left(a+1\right)2^{N}\left(\frac{a+1}{2}+1\right)_{N}
 $$ where $\left(x\right)_{N}
 $ is the [Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html). So $$\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(\frac{\beta+2k+1}{\alpha+2k+1}\right)\left(\frac{\beta+2k}{\alpha+2k}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\beta+1}{\alpha+1}\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\frac{\left(\frac{\beta+1}{2}+1\right)_{N}}{\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}+1\right)_{N}}\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+1\right)_{N}}{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}+1\right)_{N}}
 $$ and now using the [asymptotic for the Pochhammer symbol](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58231/what-is-the-stirling-formula-for-xx1x2-xn-1) we get

> $$I(\alpha,\beta)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\beta-\alpha}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{\beta+1}{2}\right)}\right)}$$ where $$\, \beta,\alpha>0,\,\beta\neq \alpha$$

as wanted.
If $\alpha=\beta=\gamma
 $ we have $$I(\gamma)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(xy\right)^{\gamma-1}}{\left(1+xy\right)\log\left(xy\right)}dxdy\stackrel{xy=u}{=}\int_{0}^{1}y^{-1}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{u^{\alpha-1}}{\left(1+u\right)\log\left(u\right)}dudy
 $$ $$\stackrel{IBP}{=}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^{\gamma-1}}{1+y}dy=\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\frac{1}{\gamma+k}=\color{red}{-\Phi\left(-1,1,\gamma\right)}
 $$ where $\gamma>0$ and $\Phi\left(x,y,z\right)$ is the [Lerch Transcendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function). Obviously for some special values of $\gamma$ we have nice closed forms. For example for $\gamma=1$ we have $$I\left(1\right)=\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\frac{1}{1+k}=-\log\left(2\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha - 1}\,\,y^{\beta - 1} \over
\pars{1 + xy}\ln\pars{xy}}\,\dd x\,\dd y} =
-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha - 1}\,\,y^{\beta - 1} \over 1 + xy}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{xy}^{z}\,\dd z}
^{\ds{-\,{1 \over \ln\pars{xy}}}}\ \,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{\alpha -1 + z}\,\,\,y^{\beta - 1 + z} \over 1 + xy}
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z =
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{xy}^{\alpha -1 + z}\,\,\,y^{\beta - \alpha - 1} \over 1 + xy}
\,\dd\pars{xy}\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}
{x^{\alpha -1 + z}\,\,\,y^{\beta - \alpha - 1} \over 1 + x}
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z =
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha -1 + z}\,\,\, \over 1 + x}\int_{x}^{1}
y^{\beta - \alpha - 1}\,\,\,\dd y\,\dd x\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \beta - \alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{\beta + z - 1}\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{\alpha + z - 1}\,\,\, \over 1 + x}
\,\dd x\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \beta - \alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{\beta + z - 1}\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{\alpha + z - 1}\,\,\, -\,\,\,
x^{\beta + z}\,\,\, +\,\,\, x^{\alpha + z} \over 1 - x^{2}}
\,\dd x\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\ &\
{1 \over 2\pars{\beta - \alpha}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}
{x^{\beta/2 + z/2 - 1}\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{\alpha/2 + z/2 - 1}\,\,\, -\,\,\,
x^{\beta/2 + z/2 - 1/2}\,\,\, +\,\,\, x^{\alpha/2 + z/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}
\,\,\,\,\dd x\,\dd z
\end{align}

---

With the *Digamma Function* identity $\pars{~\gamma\ \mbox{is the Euler-Mascheroni Constant}~}$
$$\left.\Psi\pars{\xi} =
-\gamma + \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{\xi - 1} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t\,
\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{\xi}\ >\ 0\,\,\,\,\,}
$$
the integration is reduced to:
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha - 1}\,\,y^{\beta - 1} \over
\pars{1 + xy}\ln\pars{xy}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2\pars{\beta - \alpha}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{z + \alpha \over 2} + \Psi\pars{z + \beta + 1 \over 2} -
\Psi\pars{z + \beta \over 2} - \Psi\pars{z + \alpha + 1 \over 2}}\,\dd z
\end{align}

---

Since
$\ds{\Psi\pars{\xi}\ \stackrel{\mrm{def.}}{=}\ 
\totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\xi}}}{\xi}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{\alpha - 1}\,\,y^{\beta - 1} \over
\pars{1 + xy}\ln\pars{xy}}\,\dd x\,\dd y} =
\left.{1 \over \beta - \alpha}
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z/2 + \alpha/2}\Gamma\pars{z/2 + \beta/2 + 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{z/2 + \beta/2}\Gamma\pars{z/2 + \alpha/2 + 1/2}}
\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ \infty}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{{1 \over \beta - \alpha}\,
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\bracks{\alpha + 1}/2}\Gamma\pars{\beta/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha/2}\Gamma\pars{\bracks{\beta + 1}/2}}}\,;\qquad
\Re\pars{\alpha} > 0\,,\quad\Re\pars{\beta} > 0
\end{align}

> When $\ds{\ul{\beta \to \alpha}}$, the solution becomes:
>   $$
> \half\bracks{\Psi\pars{\alpha \over 2} - \Psi\pars{\alpha + 1 \over 2}}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

$${\displaystyle \int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {x^{\alpha -1}\,y^{\beta -1}}{1+xy}}\,dx\,dy={\frac {1}{2}}\,{\frac {1}{\alpha -\beta }}\left(\left[\psi \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\beta }{2}}\right)-\psi \left({\frac {\beta }{2}}\right)\right]-\left[\psi \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\alpha }{2}}\right)-\psi \left({\frac {\alpha }{2}}\right)\right]\right)}$$

$${\displaystyle \int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {x^{\alpha -1}\,y^{\beta -1}\,(xy)^{\gamma }}{1+xy}}\,dx\,dy={\frac {1}{2}}\,{\frac {1}{\alpha -\beta }}\left(\left[\psi \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\beta }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)-\psi \left({\frac {\beta }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)\right]-\left[\psi \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\alpha }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)-\psi \left({\frac {\alpha }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)\right]\right)}$$

$${\displaystyle \int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {x^{\alpha -1}\,y^{\beta -1}\,(xy)^{\gamma }}{(1+xy)\,\log(xy)}}\,dx\,dy={\frac {1}{\alpha -\beta }}\left(\left[\log \Gamma \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\beta }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)-\log \Gamma \left({\frac {\beta }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)\right]-\left[\log \Gamma \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\alpha }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)-\log \Gamma \left({\frac {\alpha }{2}}+{\frac {\gamma }{2}}\right)\right]\right)}$$

${\displaystyle \gamma =0\,}$

$${\displaystyle \int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}{\frac {x^{\alpha -1}\,y^{\beta -1}}{(1+xy)\,\log(xy)}}\,dx\,dy={\frac {1}{\alpha -\beta }}\left(\left[\log \Gamma \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\beta }{2}}\right)-\log \Gamma \left({\frac {\beta }{2}}\right)\right]-\left[\log \Gamma \left({\frac {1}{2}}+{\frac {\alpha }{2}}\right)-\log \Gamma \left({\frac {\alpha }{2}}\right)\right]\right)}$$